# How to create tiff layers by geoserver REST API?

Tags: geoserver

I have created a coverage store in geoserver using the REST API.

http://localhost:8010/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sdwdrnTif_Test/coveragestores?configure=all

```
<coverageStore>
        <name>postman-seonyudo</name>
        <workspace>sdwdrnTif_Test</workspace>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <type>GeoTIFF</type>
        <url>file:test_TIFF/seonyudo.tif</url>
</coverageStore>
```

Coverage store has been successfully created,
so i wanted to publish a WMS layer for the coverage store.

I tried these :
1.
http://localhost:8010/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sdwdrnTif_Test/coveragestores/postman-seonyudo/coverages

```
<coverages>
    <coverage>
        <name>seonyudo</name>
    </coverage>
</coverages>
```

it returned 500 error.

2.
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sdwdrnTif_Test/coveragestores/seonyudoTEST/external.geotiff?configure=first&coverageName=seonyudoTEST

```
file://C:\tif\seonyudo2.tif
```

And it gave me a 405 err code with this message
"Error 405 Coverage store found, but it does not support resource harvesting."

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? How can I create a layer
for this store using geoserver rest API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We need to take 2 actions: a post and a put request.

first of all, you should create a coverage store with a post request using curl like the below in CMD:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "<coverageStore><name>my_store</name><workspace>cite</workspace><enabled>true</enabled></coverageStore>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/coveragestores
```

then you need to add your raster to the store with a put request:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "file:/C:/MYORTHO.tif" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/coveragestores/my_store/external.geotiff?configure=first\&coverageName=my_store
```

after executing the above command, you can see that the raster is created and published.

if you're using postman, you can extract and copy the body of the request and paste it to the body section in postman as XML.